# SQL Query to fetch number of employees joined over a calender year, broken down per month

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find the number of employees joined over a calender year, broken down on a monthly basis. So if 15 employees had joined in January, 30 in February  and so on,  the output I'd like would be

```
Month |  Employees
------|-----------
Jan   |      15
Feb   |      30
```

I've come up with a query to fetch it for a particular month

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT COUNT(EMP_NO), EMP_JN_DT
  FROM EMP_REG WHERE 
 EMP_JN_DT between '01-NOV-09'  AND '30-NOV-09'
GROUP BY EMP_JN_DT )
ORDER BY 2
```

How do I extend this for the full calender year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT   Trunc(EMP_JN_DT,'MM') Emp_Jn_Mth,
         Count(*)
FROM     EMP_REG
WHERE    EMP_JN_DT between date '2009-01-01' AND date '2009-12-31'
GROUP BY Trunc(EMP_JN_DT,'MM')
ORDER BY 1;
```

If you do not have anyone join in a particular month then you'd get no row returned. To over come this you'd have to outerjoin the above to a list of months in the required year.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT to_date(EMP_JN_DT,'MON') "Month", EMP_NO "Employees"
FROM EMP_REG
WHERE EMP_JN_DT between date '2009-01-01' AND date '2009-12-31'
GROUP by "Month"
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Ah, not valid oracle syntax though

Comment: Ah, I'm still in MySQL land! *doh*

Answer (score 0):

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/extract.php

There is a function that returns month. What you need to do is just put it in group by

Answer (score -2):

The number of employees in January can be selected in the following way:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM HIREDATE) AS MONTH1, COUNT(*)
FROM employee
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM HIREDATE)=1
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM HIREDATE)
```